# Root Number is root of unity

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, l-functions

In his thesis Tate deduces a functional equation for Hecke L-Functions associated to a unitary idele class character $\chi$ of the form
$$ L(s,\chi)=\epsilon(s,\chi)L(1-s,\overline{\chi}).$$
Here the global $\epsilon$-factor admits a factorization into its local components at a place $v$
$$\epsilon(s,\chi)=\prod_v \epsilon_v(s,\chi_v).$$
where $\chi_v$ is the component of $\chi$ at the place $v$. The local root number now is defined as $W(\chi_v)=\epsilon_v\left(\frac12,\chi_v\right)$.

I have as an exercise to show that the local root number is a root of unity if the exponent of the conductor of $\chi_v$ is not $1$.
Does anybody knows a proof or some helpful facts about this?

What I already know is that in the case where the conductor is $0$ one can express $\chi_v$ as $\chi_v=|\cdot|_v^s$ for complex $s$ and $|\cdot|_v$ is the normalized value at the place $v$. The root number can now be expressed as
$$W(\chi_v)=|\pi^d|^s$$
where $\pi$ is the local uniformizing parameter and $d$ is the exponent of the local different. Why is this a root of unity?

Comment: The exponent of the conductor is not $1$? Are you sure about this condition? For general $s$, your $W(\chi)$ just cannot be a root of unity (you’re studying the rationality of $s\ln{p}/2\pi$, since $|\pi|$ is a rational power of $p$).

Comment: @Aphelli I think you are right that for general $s$ in the unramified case (i.e. conductor 0) $W(\chi_v)$ should not be a root of unity. However I have this exercise out of the textbook "Fourier Analysis on number fields" by Ramakrishnan and Valenza (exercise 7.10 part (f)) so I highly suspect that there might be some additional properties of $s$ which I haven't used, but I cannot see which ones.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind proving the root number (under suitable conditions) is a root of unity is to appeal to the following result: an algebraic number $\alpha$ in a number field $K$ is a root of unity
iff $|\alpha|_v = 1$ for all places $v$ of $K$.
Note that if $|\alpha|_v = 1$ for all non-Archimedean places $v$ of $K$ then $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$, so
we're now reduced to an old result of Kronecker, which says an algebraic *integer* $\alpha$ is a root of unity iff
$|\alpha|_v = 1$ for all archimedean places $v$, i.e.,
$|\sigma(\alpha)| = 1$ for all archimedean embeddings
$\sigma$ of $K$ into $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$.

For a Dirichlet character with prime power conductor $p^k > 1$, you're saying its root number is a root of unity if $k \geq 2$.  To appreciate this statement, I'll tell you what happens if $k = 1$ (exponent $1$ in your terminology).

If $\chi = (\frac{\cdot}{p})$ is the Legendre symbol modulo a prime $p$ then its root number is $1$ (a trivial root of unity), but if $\chi$ is a nontrivial Dirichlet character mod $p$ that is *not* the Legendre symbol (so it is a nonquadratic character) then the root number $W(\chi)$ is *not* a root of unity.  That is due independently to Chowla and Mordell.
See S. Chowla, *On Gaussian sums*, Proc. National Acad. Sci. USA 48 (1962), 1127-1128 and L. J. Mordell, *On a cyclotomic resolvent*, Arch. Math. (Basel) 13 (1962), 486-487.  Mordell writes at the start of his paper that Chowla had conjectured the root number is not a root of unity for nontrivial characters mod $p$ other than the Legendre symbol.

For example, if $\chi \bmod 5$ is the quartic Dirichlet character where $\chi(2) = i$ then $W(\chi)^4 = -3/5 + (4/5)i$, which is not a root of unity, so $W(\chi)$ is not a root of unity.